A Sherman–Morrison-like formula
I wonder if there exists a formula for the matrix inverse of
$\begin{pmatrix}
A & uv^\text{T} \\
-uv^\text{T} & B \\
\end{pmatrix}^{-1}$,
where $A$ is a $n\times n$ matrix, $B$ is a $m\times m$ matrix, $u$ is a $n$-vector and $v$ is a $m$-vector. I think this should be a generalization of the Sherman–Morrison formula. Any help will be appreciated.

You may try the block matrix inversion formula that makes use of Schur complement.

Should the bottom-left be $-vu^T$ instead?

Your matrix doesn't make sense as written. I'll assume you mean
$$
\pmatrix{A & uv^T\\
-vu^T & B}.
$$
I will assume that $A$ and $B$ are invertible.
We can write your matrix in the form $M + UV$, where
$$
M = \pmatrix{A&0\\0&B}, \quad U = \pmatrix{0_{1 \times n}&u\\-v&0_{1 \times m}}, \quad V = \pmatrix{u^T & 0_{m \times 1}\\0_{n \times 1} & v^T}.
$$
With the Woodbury matrix identity, we find
$$
(M + UV)^{-1} = M^{-1} - M^{-1}U(I_2 + VM^{-1}U)^{-1}VM^{-1}.
$$
We have the following notable calculations:
$$
M^{-1} = \pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0 & B^{-1}}
$$
and
\begin{align}
VM^{-1}U &= \pmatrix{u^T &  0\\0 & v^T}\pmatrix{A^{-1} & 0\\0 & B^{-1}}\pmatrix{0 & u\\-v & 0}
\\ & = \pmatrix{u^T & 0\\0 & v^T}\pmatrix{0 & A^{-1}u\\-B^{-1}v & 0}
\\ & = \pmatrix{0 & u^TA^{-1}u\\-v^TB^{-1}v & 0}
\end{align}
So, the inverses that are needed for this formula are $A^{-1}, B^{-1}$, and the $2 \times 2$ matrix inverse
$$
(I + VM^{-1}U)^{-1} = \pmatrix{1 & u^TA^{-1}u\\-v^TB^{-1}v & 1}^{-1}
\\ = \frac 1{1 + (u^TA^{-1}u)(v^TB^{-1}v)}
\pmatrix{1 & -u^TA^{-1}u\\
v^TB^{-1}v & 1}.
$$

yes you are right the left bottom should be $vu^\text{T}$. thanks for the nice answer :-)
